# Как сделать insert ... on duplicate key update в Lighthouse-php на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

Как сделать **mutation** чтобы был запрос в БД `insert or update`?

В Laravel есть чудесная функция `Model::createOrUpdate($array)`, а как это сделать с помощью **lighthouse** ума не приложу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил свой вопрос созданием класса мутатора, все шаги описаны ниже

Добавляем пакет кастомных типов данных

```
composer require mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars
```

Создаем класс мутатор

```
php artisan lighthouse:mutation ClassNameMutator
```

По пути /yourPath/appName/app/GraphQL/Mutations будет создан файл ClassNameMutator.php
Пишем в самом конце свой класс createOrUpdate

```
use App\Models\ModelName;

...

public function createOrUpdate($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context)
{
    $model = ModelName::find($args['id']);
    if ($model == null) {$model = new ModelName();}
    $model->fill($args)->save();
    $model = ModelName::select($args['field'])->find($args['id']);

    return $model;
}
```

В файле /yourPath/appName/graphql/schema.graphql прописываем следующее:

```
"A Json string with format normal Array"
scalar Mixed @scalar(class: "MLL\\GraphQLScalars\\Mixed")

...

type Mutation {
    uoiModel(input: uoi! @spread): Mixed @field(resolver: "ClassNameMutator@createOrUpdate")
}
input uoi{
    id: ID!         //Поле таблицы в запрос
    otherField: ID  //Поле таблицы в запрос
    field: Mixed    //Поля, которые нужны в ответ, указываются в виде простого массива ["field1","field2","fieldn"]
}
```

Теперь у нас есть мутация, которой можно легко пользоваться, запрос будет таким:

```
mutation {
    uoiModel(
        input: {
            id: 900003
            status: 49
            field: [
                "id",
                "status"
            ]
        }
    )
}
```

Данное решение подходит для таблиц как с инкрементным id, так и без